# Circuit that acts like a NO DPST relay, but only allows switching back to closed when a reset button is pushed

Tags: electricity

I have a water pump in my van that is activated by a DPST relay when a water level switch in a water container closes. When I drive the van, the water in the tank will slosh around causing the water level to turn on and off the relay constantly. Being annoying and possibly damaging, I’d like a mechanism that will turn off power altogether to the water pump as soon as the water level sensor closes until a reset button is pushed.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you are asking. However, you should consider whether a manual reset is actually what you want. Can you provide more information about the water level switch?

Comment: do you really ant to run this while the vehicle is in motion? just asking. it would be easy to use the handbrake signal for instance...

Comment: The water level switch is a floating lever that can act as NO or NC depending on if you have it flipped over or not. When straightened it closes the circuit; when bent it’s open.

Answer (score 0):

something like this perhaps, the diode prevents the reset switch from powering the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMmvHk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>